# Why a default webrtc video capturer orientation is 90° on iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, webrtc, video-capture

Upon looking into `RTCCameraVideoCapturer.m` I found this:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
   didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
          fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
  
  #if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
  
  switch (_orientation) {
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
      _rotation = RTCVideoRotation_90;
      break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
      _rotation = RTCVideoRotation_270;
      break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
      _rotation = usingFrontCamera ? RTCVideoRotation_180 : RTCVideoRotation_0;
      break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
      _rotation = usingFrontCamera ? RTCVideoRotation_0 : RTCVideoRotation_180;
      break;
  }
  #else
    // No rotation on Mac.
    _rotation = RTCVideoRotation_0;
  #endif
}
```

Why does a default camera capturer's orientation is 90°. I made a simple voip client and the videofrom my iPhone looks rotated even when the device is in Portrait. What am I missing here? Is there any way to rotate capturer's video orientation.

Any thoughts appreciated

Comment: Honestly, I had a lot of issues with default implementation of camera capturer. So I've copied it's source, renamed to `MyCameraCapturer.m` modified and used it instead. It then allowed me to add other features, for example creating `RTCMediaTrack` and adding it to stream without actually enabling camera until required.

Comment: @DimaRostopira so you didn't have any issues with default camera capturer rotating video 90° in Portrait? Did you modify the piece of code where it determined orientation on your custom MyCameraCapturer?

Comment: I don't remember if I had an issues with orientation, just saying that you can modify it as you wish without recompiling WebRTC from source (which is a terrible experience)

Comment: @DimaRostopira Yep, I'll probably go the why with custom camera capturer. Thanks. Building webrtc really sucks but once you learn how to do it once - no problem later ))

Comment: No problem later? Ahaha, try to build it for tvOS then))

Comment: huh, tvOS is real pain

Comment: @DimaRostopira Hey, did you manage to build WebRTC for tvOS? If so, can you give me some kind of advice? Thank you so much.

Comment: @basedgod well, I did, and it worked just fine on tvOS 12-13, however after tvOS 14.0 audio output broke and I just gave up trying to fix it. Check my profile for telegram link, I will try to help you with building that

Answer (score 0):

Check `AVCaptureConnection.videoOrientation`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureconnection/1389415-videoorientation

I guess the raw orientation depends of the camera manufacturer. To offer maximum speed to client, image data are transferred straight from sensor buffer. You can't rotate capturer's video orientation. You can only mix video and interface orientation properties to properly present it to the user.

Comment: The thing is that in webrtc orientation is explicitly set as RTCVideoRotation_90 in RTCCameraVideoCapturer in Portrait which doesn't make much sense to me. Why not RTCVideoRotation_0? Camera manufacturer doesn't  seem to have anything to do with this

Comment: It has to do with "Is there any way to rotate capturer's video orientation". It must be admitted 0° orientation for video is landscape. It has been this way so long before the invention of mobile phone. Seen this way, it might have sense. I hope :)

Comment: Okay, I see. The default value fo AvCaptureConnection.videoOrientation is indeed LandscapeLeft on iPhone 11 when camera capturer starts.